# restricting different values to a single input type

Tags: javascript

I used the script on one of my scripting it was great i thought i solved the problem but whenever i change my option every button on my page chages to the same value of the option.Can i restrict my values to a single input type?
this is the script in question

```
<select>
  <option text="ok">1</option>
  <option text="hello">2</option>
  <option text="test">3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" />

$(function(){
 $('select').on('change', function(){
    $('input').val($('option:selected', this).attr('text'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

of course, just apply an `id` to the specific input and change

```
$('input').val(...)
```

into

```
$('#your-input-id').val(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is why:

```
$('input')
```

Every change of your select, you are targetting all inputs in the page. You can restrict by making the selector specific, for example:

```
$('input[type=text]')   //all inputs of type "text"
$('input[type=submit]') //all inputs of type "submit"
$('input.customButton') //all inputs of class "customButton"
```

Comment: thank you Joseph this was going to be my second question do you read people'z min :)

Answer (score 0):

If every `SELECT` menu has an `INPUT` below it that you want to update, you can do:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    $(this).next("input[type='text']").val($('option:selected', this).attr('text'));
});
```

Comment: actually it's just a single input so i won't be using this method but thanks for the quick reply.I think i am going to be a permanent follower of stackflow because of you gauys thanks a lot